# UIImageview position change programmatically iPhone

Tags: uiimageview, uitextfield

I have create a iPhone quiz application where some questions have image and some is without image. For this I took a `UItextfield` for displaying question and a `UIImageView` for displaying question Image. But when question without image is appears then the question is displayed upper size of the xib and options are displayed lower side of the xib which is not good. I want to change the position of the image view and text field with correspond to question image. How can i change the position of uicontrol?. Plz help me. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you reposition / resize a UIView.

```
CGRect frame = myControl.frame;
frame.origin.x = newX;
frame.origin.y = newY;
frame.size.width = newWidth;
frame.size.height = newHeight;
myControl.frame = frame;
```